# How can I get more accurate GPS in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

We are working on a Project Tango app in Unity and need to get fairly accurate GPS location data. Currently, the latitude and longitude provided by the API in Unity is not very precise. It says I am 50-75 feet away from where I actually am. However, Google maps shows my exact position.

Where would I start looking to tap into the data Google Maps is accessing?
I do not have a SIM card installed.

Comment: Not sure if you are using the default location provider or Google's. See: https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Comment: Maybe it is coming from permissions, that your app/games has. Have you checked in your Manifest if you have there ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. Fine location should give better results

Comment: To ask the obvious: Did you specify the desired accuracy while starting the location service? Maybe post some code?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you can't have accurate position with one captor, you need two and differential position.
The best you can have is 0,5 meter in cross country, but in urban condition our position will be at 5 meters.